# Nativescript Angular : notifying users for events which are not stored locally

Tags: angular, typescript, push-notification, nativescript

Am working on where a user chooses a class and the class schedule for the class loads. 
Whenever the user clicks the "load class schedule " button I use ngOninit to load the schedule from the server.
I would like to notify  the user 15 minutes before every time he has a class but I cant think of a way to do it since the events are not stored locally.
Am using Nativescript with angular.

Comment: Sorry, but first of all, your way of asking your question is extremly confusing. I don‘t get your point. Secondly, it‘s always good practise to add the code snippet you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to get all the events locally at some point and schedule them locally [with this](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-local-notifications) or setup push notifications and have some external process to send those.